# Unkown "create_claimable_balance" operations on my account

Tags: operations

I've just created a new account (in Public network) and have funded it with some XLM.
Only 2 minutes after, this same account has been subject to up to 9 "create_claimable_balance" operations.
I have used the Javascript SDK to create and fund the account so I'm certain these other "create_claimable_balance" operations weren't a result of my code.
Can anyone explain why this is happenning? Is it possible to avoid this?
I got the same result with another account that I created last week.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, that there are incoming claimable balances being sent to you, it is probably spam and can be ignored.

If you mean, that your account is sending out claimable balances, you should check your computer for malware.

Answer (score 0):

Some wallets (e.g. solar wallet) show all operations regarding your account. This can be confusing as when someone sends you a claimable balances (probably spam, if that account did not interact with anything else before as you just described), it is shown there.

You can query all claimable balances your account is a claimant on to verify this:
`https://horizon.stellar.org/claimable_balances/?claimant=<PUT_YOUR_ACCOUNT_HERE>`